# How to format a write protected DVD RW

Tags: dvd, storage, optical-drive

I recently brought a motherboard, with which i got a DVD for installing the drivers.Now that i had installed all the drivers i want to format it for personal use.But when I try to do so an error pops out saying that the drive is write protected.I googled about this and tried various methods but none worked.

### Methods I tried and did not work

- [Registry hack which i found in Microsoft's forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-write-protected-cd-rw/04e3dfb1-a38c-494c-9113-112d7a975ea8) It did not solve my problem.(note-this method was actually suggested for CD-RW But mine was a DVD-RW)
- [A method using Disk part which i found on Microsoft's forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-write-protected-cd-rw/04e3dfb1-a38c-494c-9113-112d7a975ea8) Disk part did not recognize my disk[image]
- Some forums suggested erasing the disk,but i did not find erase option.
- I tried out the regular way to format and 
  [image]
- I tried burning some files but windows said "Please insert a writable disk"

#### Some specs which might be useful to diagnose this issue.

- Windows 10 enterprise 64 bit
- If any other spec is required please do ask :)

Comment: If you need a DVD, why not buy one? At least in my part of the world they're quite cheap (< 1 burger / DVD). This has the added benefit of you retaining the drivers in case you have to re-install your system in a couple of years.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Lol true... I don't need the drivers anyway i have them backed up on my hard drive.....and i don't want to waste an DVD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot erase pre-mastered disks on *any* drive. Just because you have a rewritable drive ("RW") does not mean the disk itself is rewritable.

The only disks that can be written to are DVD-R, DVD+R, DVD-RW and DVD+RW disks. Only the "RW" disks can be subsequently erased in order to be reused. The "R"-only disks can only be written to, and while you can add data that "overwrites" the old data, the old data is still on the disk and can be recovered.

DVD disks that do not specify +/-R or RW will be read-only disks and you cannot format them.

Manufacturer supplied disks are not going to be writable in any way at all.

You need to buy specific disks in order to write to them.

Comment: why do manufacturers do so?... by using special disks do these manufacturers save money?..........in other words what kind of advantage does using special disks give manufactures? thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: They are not special, if anything writeable and rewritable disks are more special. Disks are bulk printed by specialised companies and are a lot cheaper than writeable disks. Think about how DVD film disks are made, the disks are not erasable after you watch a film, the same disks are used by your motherboard manufacturer.